# Xpath Sibling Text

Tags: xpath

I have been trying to figure this out for a while and can't get my head around it. I have tried using `following-sibling` but it's not working for me. The classes are really generic across the board. I was trying to use the text within the `<strong>` tag to identify then pull the sibling content:

```
<div class="generic-class">
    <p class="generic-class2">
        <strong>Content title</strong>
        "
                              Dont Need                           "
        <br>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="generic-class">
    <p class="generic-class2">
        <strong>Content title2</strong>
        "
                              Needed Content                              "
        <br>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="generic-class">
    <p class="generic-class2">
        <strong>Content title3</strong>
        "
                              Dont Need                           "
        <br>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="generic-class">
    <p class="generic-class2">
        <strong>Content title4</strong>
        "
                              Dont Need                           "
        <br>
    </p>
</div>
```

I tried using the below but with no success, I did then realise that the text is actually in the `<p>` tag so it's not a sibling.:

```
normalize-space(//*[@class="generic-class"]/p/strong/following-sibling::text())
```

Would there be a way of me finding the text in the `<strong>` tag "Content title2" and then getting the text in the parent?

Any help would be amazing, thanks!

Comment: Text of paragraph (e.g. `"Needed Content"`) is really sibling of `strong` node. Do you get no output or you get not what you want with your current XPath?

Comment: I am using a Chrome xpath extension to test and its giving Results (1) but there is nothing there, text wise.

Comment: I don't trust all those *Chrome xpath extensions...* :) Did you try your XPath in real code?

Comment: I have, i just seem to get a blank result. Same with the other expression given by Andersson

Comment: I also just noticed you are the same guy ha, There was an issue with the way i implemented your given answer, i messed up the real xpath. It's working now thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should return `"Needed Content"`:

```
normalize-space(//p/strong[.="Content title2"]/following-sibling::text())
```